# Synchronize richtextbox scrolling in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've used the following method

http://snipplr.com/view/50758/scroll-multiple-richtextboxes-or-textboxes-in-unison-synchronized-scrolling/

to scroll two richtextboxes, I ended up with the following and just called rtb1.BindScroll(rtb2)

This works but is it possible to support the wheelmouse for both? Also, pageup and down would be good.

This method promised the wheelmouse but did not work at all
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/161d1636-aea3-4fee-beb4-52370663d44c/synchronize-scrolling-in-2-richtextboxes-in-c?forum=winforms

```
   [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public class RouterRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {    
        public delegate void vScrollEventHandler(Message message);
        public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
        public event vScrollEventHandler vScroll;

        private List<RouterRichTextBox> peers = new List<RouterRichTextBox>();

        public void BindScroll(RouterRichTextBox arg)
        {
            if (peers.Contains(arg) || arg == this) 
                return; 
            peers.Add(arg);
            arg.BindScroll(this);
        }

        private void DirectWndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
            {
                foreach (RouterRichTextBox peer in peers)
                {
                    Message peerMessage = Message.Create(peer.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    peer.DirectWndProc(ref peerMessage);
                }
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for mousewheel should be enabled by adding

```
private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;
```

to your class. In WndProc add this to the if-clause

```
if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
```

to enable the use of the mousewheel. I just tested it and it works here.

For the use of PageUp or PageDown you have to research further.

Comment: Thanks, this captures the event but does not cause the other richtextbox to scroll. Surely passing the message via DirectWndProc should be sufficient

Comment: @Jaycee Well, i used your code for testing yesterday and it worked. Also for pageup/down you could have a look at `private const int VK_PRIOR = 0x21; private const int VK_NEXT = 0x22; private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;` and `(m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && (int)m.WParam == VK_PRIOR) || (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && (int)m.WParam == VK_NEXT)`, but i didn get that working reliably, so i left it out in my answer yesterday.

Comment: You are right, extracted to a new project and it works! The reason it does not work in my project is because one of the richtextboxes is set to RichTextBoxScrollBars.None. This works for scrolling using the mouse but not with the wheel